# PHP: If child array has one value only, replace the array with that value

Tags: php, arrays

My question is rather straight forward, yet I am very unsure on how to do it in an effective way.

Say we have an array like this:

```
array (
    [0] => array(
        [0] => "a"
        )
    [1] => array(
        [0] => "b"
        [1] => "c"
        )
    ["a"] => array(
       ["b"] => "d"
       )
    )
```

It does not matter to me wether or not keys are preserved, what I ultimately want to end up with is this (with or without key preservation, doesnt matter too much):

**Expected output:**

```
array (
    [0] => "a"
    [1] => array(
        [0] => "b"
        [1] => "c"
        )
    ["a"] => "d"
    )
```

I hope you can help!

~ Troels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we are inserting the first value of an array. when count of `$value` is equal to 1.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/778847)

```
<?php
$array=array (
    0 => array(
        0 => "a"
        ),
    1 => array(
        0 => "b",
        1 => "c"
        ),
    "a" => array(
       "b" => "d"
       )
    );
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    if(is_array($value) && count($value)==1)
    {
        $array[$key]=current($value); //replace array with lone value
    }
}
print_r($array);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => b
            [1] => c
        )

    [a] => d
)
```

Comment: where the php tag questions there will be @Sahil Gulati's answer :D you are too active (y)

Comment: Gonna mark your comment as the answer, as you took the fact that the value might not be an array into consideration, something I didnt account for in the example array but no doubt could happen; thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array (
    0 => array(
        0 => "a"
        ),
    1 => array(
        0 => "b",
        1 => "c"
        ),
    "a" => array(
       "b" => "d"
       )
    );
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($arr);
    foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
        if(is_array($val) && count($val) == 1){
           $arr[$key] = array_shift($val); //get first element of the array which have only one element
        }
    }
      echo "<pre>"; print_r($arr);
```

[PHP Demo](https://3v4l.org/Qmb5J)

Comment: why complicating things with array_shift() instead of a simple `$arr[$key] = $val[$key];` ?

Comment: @Jack Good question, please check array and check sub array keys, hope that will clear your doubt. We don't know the key of sub array thats why I used `array_shift()`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$temp = array (
    0 => array(
        0 => "a"
        ),
    1 => array(
        0 => "b",
        1 => "c"
        ),
    "a" => array(
       "b" => "d"
       )
    );
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($temp);
     $new_arr = array();

 foreach ($temp as $key => $value) {
    if(count($value)>1)
        $new_arr[$key] = $value;
    else
    {
        $new_arr[$key] = array_shift($value);
    }
 }
 echo '<pre>'; print_r($new_arr);
```